# Алгоритм детектирования смены фазы сигнала

Tags: c++

есть сигнал с ФРМ(фазоразностной) модуляцией в виде массива PCM-отсчетов
[image: Пример смены фазы сигнала]

[image: Еще пример смены фазы]

Нужен алгоритм:

1. Обнаружения момента смены фазы
2. Определения начальной фазы сигнала после смены фазы

В ЦОС(DSP) я новичок. Прошу сильно не пинать!

Answer (score 1):

Ну давайте порассуждаем.

На входе есть сигнал с постоянной амплитудой и частотой, который можно описать

```
Sig = A * Cos(w*t + fi)
```

[Перемножим](http://www.cleverstudents.ru/trigonometry/product_of_sin_and_cos.html) этот сигнал с косинусом и синусом той же частоты с нулевой фазой:

```
CC = Sig * C = A * Cos(w*t + fi) * Cos(w*t) = A/2 * (Cos(fi) + Cos(2*w*t + fi))
SS = Sig * S = A * Cos(w*t + fi) * Sin(w*t) = A/2 * (-Sin(fi) + Sin(2*w*t + fi))
```

Отфильтруем высокую частоту. В простейшем случае - с помощью Low-Pass Filter /ФНЧ, собственно - сгладить, а можно и режекторным фильтром попробовать (не уверен, что это не внесёт артефактов).

В результате получатся две величины, примерно постоянные, пока фаза не меняется, пропорциональные косинусу и синусу фазы. А саму фазу можно получить, используя арктангенс

```
fi = atan2(-SS, CC)
```

В момент изменения фазы полученное значение fi должно претерпеть скачок.

Comment: скачек будет и в случае показанном на самом верхнем рисунке?

Comment: одна загвоздка - частота сигнала неизвестна

Comment: Для фазовой модуляции частота обычно известна, в электронных устройствах делают только автоподгонку точной частоты гетеродина. Частоту сигнала можно измерить с помощью автокорреляции. Если сигнал такого качества, как нарисовано (что вряд ли) - можно просто считать переходы через 0.

Comment: ок. попробую                                 спасибо!

Comment: Еще - ко мне приходит "кусок" массива отсчетов - небольшой буфер и, соответственно, я не могу узнать t для отсчета - как быть?

Comment: Если буферы независимы - каждый раз t начинать с нуля.

Comment: Что значит "независимы" dsp заполняет буфер отсчетами, выталкивает и так далее... А если перемножить произвольный отсчет на синус, например, 0-го отсчета, то , на мой взгляд будет фигня.... Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Значит, ваши буфера связаны друг с другом, и значение t нужно продолжать с прошлого буфера - если один закончился на значении 3.0 сек., то первое значение нового буфера будет с t=3.0+1/Fдискретизации